# Error: AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, numpy

The following code throws the error `Error: AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'append'`

```
 salary=np.array
    rescaled=np.array
    for item in finance_features:
        salary.append(item[0])
        rescaled.append(item[1])
    print salary
    print rescaled
```

Someone who can help me please, I appreciate in advance

Comment: You want to use numpy or a normal list you work?

Comment: You can create salary and rescaled as empty lists `salary=[]
 rescaled=[]` and it works

Comment: I want tot use numpy array.

Comment: I think the problem is the declaration of the arrays. If you want to create an empty array you should use np.empty(shape). If you want to check it by yourself you can take the first two lines,  take out the for loop and say print(type(salary), type(rescaled)) in order to see what objects this variables are

Comment: You don't want to `append` to a numpy array.  You can only append to a list!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about defining an empty numpy array and use np.append to append to array inside for loop?

```
salary=np.array([])
rescaled=np.array([])

for item in zip(range(10), range(10,20)):
    salary = np.append(salary, item[0])
    rescaled = np.append(rescaled, item[1])
print(salary)
print(rescaled)
```

Comment: can you also explain to me your "for item in zip(list(range(10)), list(range(10,20))):"

Comment: zip returns iterator of tuples from two lists, its just to mimic your `finance_features` iterator. You can check the examples in [https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip]

Comment: Stick with list append.  Repeated array append like this is slower!  If I had my way, I'd remove the `np.append` function.